# AWS DMS task fails to retrieve tables

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-dms

I'm trying to migrate existing data and replicate ongoing changes
the source database is PostgreSQL it's managed by aws.
the target is kafka.
I'm facing the below issue.

`Last Error No tables were found at task initialization. Either the selected table(s) or schemas(s) no longer exist or no match was found for the table selection pattern(s). If you would like to start a Task that does not initially capture any tables, set Task Setting FailOnNoTablesCaptured to false and restart task. Stop Reason FATAL_ERROR Error Level FATAL`

Comment: Facing same issue with one of my new DMS tasks with Postgresql as a source.

Comment: @Suz'lShrestha try to set database name postgres in the endpoint

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. I was using database user that is not root(or user that doesn't have enough permission). Once I started using the root user for the DMS task, everything went smooth.

AWS DMS postgresql as a source documentation link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.PostgreSQL.html